# Adding paintcode stylekit images to storyboard not showing preview

Tags: paintcode

I'm following the instructions for adding stylekit images to storyboards by adding an object, setting it's class to stylekit and then right click dragging to the UIImage from the stylekit object - however I'm not seeing the images show up in  UIImageView preview in the storyboard.  The image is there when I run the code however.

Is there a different series of steps I need to take?  I'm using ios9 xcode 7.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder doesn’t allow previewing this kind of connections. To see the image in IB, you will need to subclass the view, mark it as `@IBDesignable` and override `drawRect` method, where you call the StyleKit drawing method.